# Where do I download GNOME Boxes after Installation via Linux Terminal?

Tags: gnome, package-management, windows, downloads

I'm trying to put WINDOWS in, aside, or next to, Linux OS. Despite how many ways there are, I downloaded GNOME Boxes through the Linux Terminal. It says do that, then "double-click" dL? Am I supposed to put something else in the terminal?
I really need help you guys... I produce alot of music per week (instrumental beats) and my original Software (NCH MixPad//FL Studio) won't dL for Linux :(

I need a complete walk-through so I can use my music software properly again.

Comment: Packages are built for specific OS/releases, so provide yours would be useful if you want specific help that will work reliably. Please tell us and don't make us guess your product & release details.

Comment: You're suggesting i find out my OS, or OS Release? I'm on Ubuntu (latest update), Linux. Still new to Linux, so if there's any answer you want direct, be very specific about what you want to know, or i'll unintentionally waste time for us.

Comment: I'm still new to it's terminal system. So i'm, also, unfamiliar with it.

Comment: If I want to look up my release time of my distribution, how do i do that and is it through the terminal?

Comment: So you're using the *latest* Ubuntu, which is Ubuntu 23.10 (the 2023-October release)?  Is this a Ubuntu 23.10 Server install? or Ubuntu 23.10 Desktop install? (some different defaults) as its best if you just tell us rather than guess. Many people only consider the LTS release for example, thus the *latest* to them is 3 releases ago being Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (*not the latest release; but latest LTS*).  Some details on your system can be obtained by `lsb_release -a` but I'd expect release details were known if new system.

Comment: Yes the Oct, 2023 release. I believe it just updated, days ago.. No, it's a Desktop install.

Comment: Thank you for that link! This is what I was prompt with :)

Comment: when user typed: lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
Release: 20.04

Comment: Please add additional details to your question, this is a *Question & Answer* site and not a [forum](https://ubuntuforums.org/), answers to your question will be to your question (*which currently doesn't mention any release*). Ubuntu 20.04 is the 2020-April release, so is more than 3 years old now & far from the *latest* (*it's the oldest release still on-topic on this site*). The final .6 is an indication of update level (& kernel if using HWE; Desktop installs of 20.04.6 default to HWE which is the 5.15 kernel for example; `uname -r` will show kernel detail)

Comment: Oh my, thank you! This is my kernel detail: 5.15.0-86-generic
A link to the newest Desktop release for Ubuntu , do you know it? Also, what is your next suggested step; what should I do (next) in order to download GNOME BOXES? Is it wise to update my Linux?

Comment: FYI:  As for kernel, I only worry about the first two numbers; ie. 5.15 is the HWE kernel for 20.04; the 86 is your upgrade/security level as regards patches applied; 5.4 is the GA kernel stack for 20.04. Ubuntu 20.04 released in 2020-April (thus 20.04 given *year.month* format used; 2000 subtracted from year) has 5 years of supported life; so is supported until 2025-April. Your choice if you want newer software (*upgrade to 22.04 or two years newer*). I understood your question as being about installing it (*not using it*) so answered as such..

Comment: You're now asking about how to use it (*maybe that was your intention initially & I missed it; if so I'm sorry*).  I'm no expert with the app as I don't use it; I'll suggest you start a new question; alternatively you could refine your question and un-accept my answer (*question currently says answered*) to get more attention, but new question will be easier. I'll provide a help link https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-boxes/stable/ but sorry as I'm not a user of it, I'm not qualified to help sorry.

Comment: Thank you for all of this though! Well I figured out how to install it... I'll post another question.

Answer (score 0):

To install [`gnome-boxes`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal-updates/gnome-boxes) you can just

`sudo apt install gnome-boxes`

If you look at the link I provided (*showing the package that will install with my provided command*), you'll note it's found in the 'universe' or community sourced packages for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, thus *universe* needs to be enabled.

If you don't have *universe* enabled, you can enable it with

`sudo add-apt-repository universe`

Comment: Oh, it looks like universe is already securely installed. And so is the GNOME Boxes. Okay so, now that those are installed correctly, what's my next step?